# Transceiver for MM links up to 2k

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst, fiber, layer1, transceiver

I have 2 links of 1.5 mm f.o mm c / u I want to know if a transceiver GLC-GE-100FX would work for me, why and what are its variations.

Comment: Removed the off-topic resource request.

Comment: You need to tell us in what device you want you want to use this transceiver.

Comment: It is a Cisco 2960-24LC-s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cisco GLC-SX-MM **for gigabit** should be [compatible with your 2960](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/interfaces_modules/transceiver_modules/compatibility/matrix/GE_Tx_Matrix.html?#_Toc507582014) - some vendors offer compatible SFPs using 1310 nm wavelength for 2 km MMF ("Cisco GLC-SX-MM-2K compatible").

Comment: ¿al usar este tipo de GIBIC es recomendable u obligatorio usar un mode conditioning patch (MCP) ?

Comment: Please try to use English, this site is intended as a Q&A collection. "Is it advisable or mandatory to use a conditioning patch (MCP) when using this type of GIBIC? " No, this SFP should be intended directly for MMF. An -LX10 (intended for SMF) type might not work.

Answer (score 2):

Simply searching the Cisco web site produces the answer. According to [*Cisco 100-Megabit Ethernet SFP Modules Compatibility Matrix*](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/interfaces_modules/transceiver_modules/compatibility/matrix/100MB_Tx_Matrix.html), that transceiver is compatible with your switch:

[image]

The GLC-GE-100FX uses MMF for up to 2 kilometers:

[image]

You need to make sure that 100BASE-FX is what you really want. That is a very old standard that is not well supported in modern equipment.

Comment: si, algo anticuado. en el caso de tener un 1000BASE-LX/LH SFP (para otro equipo) este se puede adaptar con algo mas para que logre los 2k?

Comment: 1000BASE-LX beyond ca. 550 m requires single-mode fiber, I'm afraid.